# Translation for node references not working properly

Tags: 7, nodes, i18n-l10n

I have two content types: product feature and product. Both can be translated. If I create English product and assign many product features (by node reference inside field collection) and then create translation (ex. French) for this I have rewritted product features. Then I can select Product features translated previously to French. English product have English product features and French product (translated) have French product features (also translated).

PROBLEM:
When I modify French node (change product features to French) my English node is also changed (product features are French).

Did I missed something?

Comment: I am also having the same problem, any luck solving it?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is to remove all elements in field collection of translated node and add them once again - with properly translated elements/values.

Answer (score 0):

There's a module for that: https://drupal.org/project/i18n_node_reference

> Provides i18n field synchronisation for a node_reference field.
>
> The referenced nodes are translated into the correct language. If no
>   such language exists, it is ignored. This is the same functionality as
>   is supported by the taxonomy reference translation in i18n_taxonomy.